# How can I unit test infoDictionary behavior

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

Lets say that my SUT (system under test) needs to supply the `@"CFBundleIdentifier"` from `infoDictionary` in a property bundleIdentifier.

```
- (void)testAppPackageName
{
    //fixture code is happening in setUp function
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(sut.bundleIdentifier, [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"]);
}
```

The problem is that `[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]` returns an empty `NSDictionary` in test environment, which means I am testing nil equal nil here.
Also, this test smells

How would you test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution I used for now is to inject the inforDictionary to my sut in the constructor

```
- (void)testAppPackageName
{
   //fixture
   NSDictionary* appInfo = @{  @"CFBundleIdentifier" :  BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER};
   sut = [[SomeClass alloc] initWithInfo:appInfo];

   XCTAssertEqualObjects(sut.bundleIdentifier, BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER);
}
```